# Having "Allow remote connections to this server" disabled I still can connect from another machine

Tags: sql-server, connection, server-configuration

I have a Window server with a SQL Server 2017 for which I locally have disabled the "Allow remote connections to this server" option.

Nevertheless, I still can connect to that SQL Server from my personal PC by using SSMS.

How is it possible if remote connections are not allowed?

Or, what are exactly the so called remote connections?

Comment: Check `EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access'` run_value = 0

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, the [deprecated `remote access` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option) does not control whether SQL Server allows remote connections. SSCM is used to configure whether remote access is allowed.

Comment: Did you configure the SQL Server Network configuration using SQL Server Configuration Manager (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc)?

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman, you made me read a little. To be honest, I have never used that option but only SSCM.

Comment: Executing "exec sys.sp_configure N'remote access', 1/0" or using the checkbox in the SSMS server connections properties seem to be the same. Aditionally I have verified that the SSMS checkbox for allowing remote connections controls neither the remote connections nor the remote procedures execution. It doesn't work. Alternatively I used the SSCM to disable TCP/IP protocol while enabling Named Pipes protocol and then accessed the SQL Server locally. This allows blocking the remote connections since I think usually they are carried out by using TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

This option seems to imply "Allow connecting to this server across a network", but that is not correct (even though I've been guilty of thinking that was the case for more than 10 years!)

The answer (as given by Dan Guzman above as a comment) is the correct answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Even the "experts" have got it wrong; notice in their knowledge-base article, they suggest checking the box as the first step! https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/